# cvDCT in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

i was wondering how to use   cvDCT void in opencv c++

if anyone have an example

Answer (score 2):

[The manual](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html#cv-dct) explains both the parameters and the inner workings of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
IplImage* src0 = cvLoadImage(strPath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
IplImage* src = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src0), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
cvConvert(src0, src);
IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src0), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);

cvDCT(src, dst, 0);
//cvDCT (dst, src, 1);
//cvConvert(src, src0);
cvShowImage("Source", src0);
```